# Google Actions Simulator MalformedResponse Media response is not supported on this device

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I have been testing my app on the google actions simulator, mainly using the 'Smart Display' surface.

Until this morning it was working fine but then suddenly I started getting this error:

```
MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].media_response: Media response is not supported on this device..
```

I only get this error with the 'Smart Display' and 'Speaker' surfaces but not the 'Phone' surface.

When I look in the 'REQUEST' tab when using 'Phone' surface I see `"name": actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO` in the JSON under `"capabilities"`, but it's not there when I use 'Smart Display' or 'Speaker'.

Has anyone encountered this problem before ?

I did not change any code that would affect this and besides it does not seem to be related to my code at all..

I would be grateful for any advice on the matter.

-ben

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this is happening, and this appears to be a bug with the simulator.

It is still working correctly with real devices.

I've reported this to Google and been told it has been filed as a bug in their internal tracker, but there is no word about time to fix.

**Update**

This should now be fixed.

Comment: Oh so it's not just me? That's a relief, I have been going crazy all day trying to figure out what I did to cause this. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Nope, not just you! I assumed it was just me when I saw it, and then I saw your question.

Comment: Well now it seems to work again so I guess they fixed it!

Comment: Heh... just after I posted my last comment, I got official word that it might be working again. So yup - they fixed it!